# Perl, how to read from stdin outside a loop?

Tags: perl, input, readfile

There is something I don't understand :

say `in` is a file containing :

```
1
2
3
```

and `foo.pl` :

```
use strict;
<>;
print;
<>;
print;
<>;
print;
```

and then run :

```
perl foo.pl < in
```

**Why this programm doesn't output anything ?**

...While this one :

```
use strinct;
while(<>) {
    print;
}
```

output the whole file

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Because

```
while(<>)
```

Is shorthand for

```
while($_ = <>)
```

Which means the line is assigned to the default variable `$_`. Which is also used by `print`.

What you wrote:

```
<>;
```

Does not assign anything to `$_`. It is just a readline in void context, which means the value is discarded and not stored anywhere. Hence `$_` is empty. If you `use warnings`, Perl will tell you what is going on.

```
Use of uninitialized value $_ in print
```

If you do the assignment manually it will work:

```
$_ = <>;
```

Note also that you do not have to redirect the file content, you can just supply the file name as an argument:

```
perl foo.pl in
```

Comment: I know, my question is why the first doesn't output anything ?

Comment: ok, thx :) for the curiosity, is there a way of doing `$_ = <>; print;` without doing the assignment manually ?

Comment: @hl037_ Well... `print <>` will print all lines. You can also do a postfix loop: `print for <>`. If you want to just print one line, `print scalar <>` (or any other method for putting the file handle in scalar context, e.g. `print "" . <>`). TIMTOWTDI is the Perl way.

Comment: <pedantic>`while(<>)` is shorthand for `while(defined($_=<>))`</pedantic>

Comment: @mob Yes, in the original answer I had included that part, but I removed it, since I felt it would distract from the main point.